# Juju bootstrap gives me a "409 CONFLICT" error

Tags: juju, maas

am defining a Juju environment on Ubuntu 12.04LTS but when i give command "juju bootstrap", it generates error i.e

```
Unexpected Error interacting with provider: 409 CONFLICT
2012-04-13 02:25:01,025 ERROR Unexpected Error interacting with provider: 409 CONFLICT
```

My environments.yaml file is like:

```
environments:
  maas:
    type: maas
    maas-server: 'http://127.0.0.1:80/MAAS'
    maas-oauth: 'YQB6PzembfZtLzgy9q:9tzQyQpCbAG38Vf5Ph:EuNhAmH4LXrLJ6wtBUrYqe9wrwCyJrHf'
    admin-secret: 'nothing'
    default-series: precise
```

Answer (score 4):

`CONFLICT` from maas means that it doesn't have any nodes available for juju to acquire (juju bootstrap needs to boot a node).

It's not the best error unfortunately, juju needs fixing to show all the text. You need the server edition of 12.04

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error after deciding to start over with a fresh Juju setup and forgetting to run `juju destroy-environment` before deleting my Juju config (`~/.juju`). This left my MaaS setup thinking it was currently deployed to while my new Juju setup had never been bootstrapped. This lead to getting the `409 CONFLICT` conflict error.

When I tried to connect my new configuration to the same MaaS, it gave that error. I even tried manually deallocating all the nodes in the MaaS thinking it was having some trouble there.

But that's not what the problem was. MaaS stores files, some of them including the Juju bootstrapped state.

To reset this, you need to run:

```
maas-cli login root http://<your_MaaS_server_hostname>/MAAS/
maas-cli root files list
```

See if any of the files listed have the filename `bootstrap-verify` or `provider-state`. If so, run the following commands to remove the files and reset the MaaS to being in an "Non bootstrapped" state:

```
maas-cli root file delete bootstrap-verify
maas-cli root file delete provider-state
```

Run `juju status`. If it gives you an error that indicates it is not bootstrapped, simply run `juju bootstrap` and you should be good to go. If it gives some other error indicating that it thinks it's deployed but can't find a file or something, then remove the folder `~/.juju/environments/` (maybe back it up just in case), and then run `juju bootstrap`.